# Spring not serving static files with unknown extensions

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I use tag `<mvc:resources .../>` to map static content. Everything works great as long as I don't try to access file with an unknown file extension, for example some *.less file. When I try to access to a file with such an extension, I get 404 error. If I change the extension of the file to e.g. *.css, it works fine. If I don't use `<mvc:resources .../>` and map the default servlet to static content, there is no problem either.

Do you know how to fix it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your complete `<mvc:resources .../>` entry from the config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Tomcat? If so, try adding a `mime-mapping` element in the `web.xml`:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>less</extension>
    <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type> <!-- Or whatever. -->
</mime-mapping>
```